# pass an argument to function, recieving end says undefined

Tags: javascript

I check with alert if the variables are like how I want them to be. This is true they are like I want.

```
var fri = "YES"     //mon til sun are defined but for readibilty I didnt post them all strings
alert(mon + tue + wed + thu + fri + sat + sun)
setInterval(dailytimer, 999, (mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun));
```

but the recieving code has this problem.

```
function dailytimer (mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun){
  alert (fri);}
```

I want this code to alert

> YES!

but it alerts:

> undefined

where am I going wrong

Comment: It's not a proper way to use `setInterval`...

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the arguments to be passed.

Comment: `setInterval(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)`

Comment: I will give that a try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun)
```

This is an expression using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), an operator which should have never existed; it’s equivalent to `sun`. You’re looking to pass all the arguments to `setInterval`, which works just like any other function:

```
setInterval(dailytimer, 999, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun);
```

Alternatively, you can create a function to call `dailytimer` with the appropriate arguments and pass that:

```
setInterval(function () {
    dailytimer(mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun);
}, 999);
```

This has the advantage of working in IE9 and earlier if you care about those browsers, and might be easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are only passing one variable to `dailytimer`:

```
setInterval(dailytimer, 999, (mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun));
```

What you should be doing is:

```
setInterval(dailytimer, 999, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun);
```

OR:

```
setInterval(function(){ dailytimer(mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun); }, 999);
```